# how to dynamically change materialize.css icons

Tags: javascript, html, icons, materialize

I have a bootstrap dropdown collapse.
I use it as a dropdown megamenu .
there is an icon that I want it changed by clicking on it. and I use materialize.css icons pack, so I have to change the text, not the class.
I used this

```js
    function ChangeIcon(){
      document.getElementById("icon-change").textContent="close";
}
```

```html
<i onclick="ChangeIcon()" id="icon-change" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mega-menu-dropdown" class="material-icons">menu</i>
```

but the problem is, when I want to close it ,the icon doesn't change to its first type ( menu  -> close    and vice versa ).
what should I do to solve this prob ?

Comment: `if(document.getElementById("icon-change").textContent == 'menu') document.getElementById("icon-change").textContent="close"; 
else if(document.getElementById("icon-change").textContent == 'close') document.getElementById("icon-change").textContent="menu";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function ChangeIcon(_this){
    if(_this.textContent === "close") {
        _this.textContent = "menu";
    } else {
        _this.textContent = "close";
    }
}

<i onclick="ChangeIcon(this)" id="icon-change" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mega-menu-dropdown" class="material-icons">menu</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check text content first, then change it accordingly:

```js
    function ChangeIcon(){
      if(document.getElementById("icon-change").textContent == 'menu') document.getElementById("icon-change").textContent="close";
      else if(document.getElementById("icon-change").textContent == 'close') document.getElementById("icon-change").textContent="menu";
}
```

```html
<i onclick="ChangeIcon()" id="icon-change" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mega-menu-dropdown" class="material-icons">menu</i>
```